# find a pattern from grep in bash for computing average memory usage of android app

Tags: android, regex, bash, shell

I want to get the average memory usage of some android app. All I want to do is to fetch only the memory usage. For example, below script provide instantaneous memory usage of `mobile_cep` application

`adb shell dumpsys meminfo | grep mobile_cep`

gives output as

```
233,328K: org.carleton.iot.mobile_cep (pid 27060 / activities)
```

While I am interested in getting `233,328K` value. I want to repeat this process several times and get an average value for memory usage. I am using below script to print `233,328K` value.

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
while [ $counter -le 10 ]
    do
        ((counter++))
        val1=$(adb shell dumpsys meminfo | grep mobile_cep)
        val2=$($val1 | grep -i '\d\d\d,\d\d\dK') 
        echo $val2
    done
echo  done
```

however, I am not getting the desired result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$val1 | grep -i '\d\d\d,\d\d\dK'` will try to *execute* the value of `$val1` as a command.

Comment: `\d\d\d,\d\d\dK` seems a little too conservative. What if it’s less than 100,000? What if it’s in megabyte rather than kilo-?

Comment: @Biffen : you are right, this pattern will not work for all cases. However, right now I just want things working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping to `sed`:

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo | grep mobile_cep | sed 's/:.*//'
```

It is also trivial with `awk` if you are able to execute an `awk` script you don't need `grep` either:

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo | awk -F'[: ]' '/mobile_cep/ { print $1 }'
```

Comment: The first command worked but not second when I used it in terminal